# Swift: Error while Parsing JSON data from alamofire into array with Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, sdwebimage

I have the below `JSON` response and i want to get the `id` and `url`.

```
[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  }]
```

And in view controller I have coding as following.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SDWebImage


class AlbumResponse: Codable {
    var list: Int
    var hits: [Album]
}


class Album: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var title : String
    var url: String
    var thumbnailUrl : String
}



class CollectionView: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let url1 = ["JSON URL"]
    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
    var arrList = [Album]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reequest()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.collection.reloadData()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrList.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: firstCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! firstCollectionViewCell
        let objct = arrList[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text =  String(objct.id)
        cell.img!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: objct.url), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "download"), options: .retryFailed, completed: nil)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 5 * 2 ) / 2 //some width
        let height = width * 1.45 //ratio
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }


    func reequest() {

        let url = URL(string: "JSON URL")
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON {(response) in

            switch (response.result){
            case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(AlbumResponse.self, from: data)
                        self.arrList = response.hits
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collection.reloadData()
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("error to print the data \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run it's showing black screen

Comment: A black screen doesn't mean that its a problem parsing the JSON, it could be something completely different. Are you sure this screen is actually loading on screen, you set your collectionView constraints? outlet? changed the background colour of the view and collection view to different colours to see what is showing? try to get to the black screen and debug the view hierarchy which will show you what is shown on screen

Comment: try with `let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Album].self, from: data)` I think that is what are you receiving, let me know if solves your issue

Comment: There is no key `hits` on your JSON. Don't you have an error message? And do `print(error)` instead of `print(error.localizedDescription)`. It's important to read error message. Even if you don't understand it, share it with us. `let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(AlbumResponse.self, from: data); self.arrList = response.hits` => `self.arrList = JSONDecoder().decode([Album].self, from: data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and I just find the correct way. Here is the correct code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SDWebImage


class Album: Codable {
    var url : String
    var id : Int
}


class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
    var urls = URL(string: "my Url")

    var arrList = [Album]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        request()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let obj = arrList[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = String(obj.id)
        cell.imageview!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: obj.url), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "6-things-main"), options: .cacheMemoryOnly, completed: nil)
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 1 * 2 ) / 2
    let height = width * 1.45
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    func request() {

        let url = URL(string: "my url")
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON {(response) in

            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Album].self, from: data)
                        self.arrList = response
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collection.reloadData()
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            case .failure( let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment if you have still face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, like Scrpitable said it might not be anything to do with your code for the black screen.  For instance whenever I get a black screen the first thing I check is that that "Is Initial View Controller" is checked for one of my views.  Sometimes if I forget to set the Initial view it just shows a black screen.  I'll add a screenshot to what I mean.[image]

Comment: No that's not an issues.